# django dev console error

Tags: django

can anyone give me more information on the following error I found in my dev console:

```
[18/May/2011 17:48:46] "GET /static/search_bar/logout-dark.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1579
[18/May/2011 17:48:46] "GET /static/search_bar/searchBar.png HTTP/1.1" 200 277
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 300, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 286, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[18/May/2011 17:48:49] "GET /static/search_bar/settings-light.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1486
[18/May/2011 17:58:16] "GET /static/search_bar/mail-light.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1704
```

It's between calls to different images so I don't know where it's really coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/4444

```
This is common error which happens whenever your browser closes the connection while the dev server is still busy sending data. The best we could is to have a more explicit error message.
```

Comment: does this mean it's a problem? Or just something that happens?